# Scala: Use implicit parameter in different way or change implementation logic?

Tags: scala

I've those assets

```
trait CronoTrait {

  def time[B](label: String = "")(x: => B): B = {
    val labelWrapped: Option[String] = if ("".equals(label)) None else Some(label)
    val crono:Crono = Crono(labelWrapped)
    Crono.crono = crono  //override implicit crono istance
    crono.reset
    crono.start
    crono.result = x
    crono.end
    crono.printTime
    crono.printCheckPointsReport()
    crono.result.asInstanceOf[B]
  }


  def time[B](x: => B): B = {
    time("")(x)
  }

  def checkPoint(implicit crono: Crono) {
    crono.addCheckPoint()
  }
}

case class Crono(val label: Option[String] = None) {
   //methods
}

object Crono {
   implicit var crono = new Crono()
}
```

and I use them like this:

```
import Crono.crono

time("rootCrono") {
  //operations
  checkPoint  //rootCheckPoint
  time("innerCrono") {
  //operations
  checkPoint  //innerCheckpoint
  //operations
  }
}
```

and I obtain in output:

```
crono [rootCrono] - reset
crono [innerCrono] - reset
crono [innerCrono] - 46 ms
crono [innerCrono] - checkPoint-1 --> elapsed time: 24 - checkpoint time: 24 ms
crono [rootCrono] - 99 ms
crono [rootCrono] - checkPoint-1 --> elapsed time: 28 - checkpoint time: 28 ms
```

Now everything works fine but I understand the implementation is horrible (using an implicit var and changing it I think it's not so thread safe).
So, i need to change the logic or can I use implicit in a different way?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do. Why do you have a global mutable variable _at all_? Why is it implicit? Where is `CronoTrait` used?

Comment: Maybe you want [`DynamicVariable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.DynamicVariable)?

Comment: because I want to use checkPoint method inside time parameter using his crono istance

Comment: Is there special functionality in your subclasses of `CronoTrait`?

Comment: no I haven't subclasses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for global variables here. You want your implicit values to be scoped, not global or simply thread-local, so, just do that, with implicit parameters. Remove your `implicit var chrono`.

```scala
def time[B](label: String = "")(x: Chrono => B) {
  // ...
  crono.result = x(chrono)
  // ...
}

time("rootCrono") { implicit chrono =>
  // ...
  checkPoint
  time("innerCrono") { implicit chrono =>
    // ...
    checkPoint
    // ...
  }
}
```

Furthermore, there's a better way to import method names in Scala than defining and mixing in an otherwise useless trait. Just define in an object and use `import`:

```scala
object Chrono {
  def time[B](...) { ... }
  def checkPoint(...) { ... }
}

import Crono._
time("...") { ... }
```

Also, instead of using an `asInstanceOf` cast, you should be able to parameterize `Chrono` as `Chrono[B]`, with `B` as the type of `result`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a [dynamic variable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.DynamicVariable) rather than implicit values.

```
trait CronoTrait {
  def time[B](label: String)(x: => B): B = {
    Crono.crono.withValue(Crono(if (label.isEmpty) None else Some(label))) {
      val crono = Crono.crono.value
      crono.reset()
      crono.start()
      crono.result = x
      crono.end()
      crono.printTime()
      crono.printCheckPointsReport()
      crono.result.asInstanceOf[B]
    }
  }

  def time[B](x: => B): B =
    time("")(x)

  def checkPoint() =
    Crono.crono.value.addCheckPoint()
}

case class Crono(label: Option[String] = None) {
  // methods
}

object Crono {
  val crono = new DynamicVariable[Crono](Crono())
}
```

And then:

```
time("rootCrono") {
  checkPoint()
  time("innerCrono") {
    checkPoint()
  }
}
```

This is thread-safe because dynamic variables have a different stack for each thread.

You should avoid mutability as much as possible. It makes maintaining code very difficult. It looks like you're trying to write Scala as if it were Java (mutable variables, `equals` instead of `==`, etc).

Comment: Yes I like it much better. Btw import Crono.crono.value._ doesn't work

Comment: thanks it works, I use @DanGetz version because is perfect for my needs.